# how to handle" System.InvalidCastException: when Deserializing the result of an API call

Tags: c#, api, deserialization, nullreferenceexception, dotnet-httpclient

I am not sure I framed the title properly, but I hope i get some assistance regardless. I am trying to consume an api but i keep getting "JsonSerializationException: Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Double". This happens when I try to deserialize in the line labeled as **Error Line** in the code just at the bottom

```cs
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetSalaryHistoryResponse>();
```

During the API call, I noticed about two fields with null values, which could be what is triggering the error

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("API_KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("REQUEST_ID", "xxxxxxxx");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MERCHANT_ID", "xxxxxxxx");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("AUTHORIZATION", "ConsumerKey=Q1dHREVNTzEyMzR8Q1dHREVNTw==,ConsumerToken=c5e8db0cbca54593e54f6702778d1ea129463d5555166cd1d0c46416495df82483a08c30fdd1e9fa39ceeea9bc6d8da9ba892ff3c3f326d537bc06bf8ef3ece7");

    string vv = request.ToJson();
    var content = new StringContent(request.ToJson(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var responseTask = client.PostAsync("provideCustomerDetails", content);
    responseTask.Wait();
    var result = responseTask.Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        readTask.Wait();
        var a = readTask.Result.ToString();
***Error Line:>* **     var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetSalaryHistoryResponse>(readTask.Result);
         
        return response ;
    }
}
```

I saw a hint to use the code snippet below, I also replaced `attributesObject` with the class property and still get the error. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. i just want to be able to send the value of the Deserialization as a return value and use it elsewhere, can anyone help ?

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    attributesObject,      
    Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    });
```

Comment: why not await the task ?  `var result = await client.PostAsync("provideCustomerDetails", content);`

Comment: using await will require i decorate the method with "Async" which in turn will provoke other issues that i am not used to. i figured responseTask.Wait(); will do the same thing. Futhermore i am calling the api for use in a webform. i am not sure how some features works

Answer (score 0):

do not use .Result, or .Wait method if you don't want to use async/await in the method. Use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() in this case. I could imagine your method similar to this:

```
var response = client.PostAsync("provideCustomerDetails", content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
{
   var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DesiredTypeHere>(content, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
   return deserialized;
}
```

Comment: please what is this "DesiredTypeHere" ?

Comment: Ahh sorry I provided an example with generic overload of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject - if you know the properties/type that the result will contain, you can directly deserialize it to that type using DeserializeObject<T>. In case you don't want to use generics or you don't know the result, simply use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, jsonSerializerSettings)

Comment: i actually tried this , i still get a Null ...